# how do i fix this no matching function for call to 'stoi(int&)'|

Tags: c++, c++11, codeblocks

i keep getting this error. i know this is a c++ 11 function but it still isnt working with code blocks c++ compiler. am i using this function correctly of is it a problem with the codeblocks compiler. i tried changing the compiler. using the "have g++ follow the c++11 iso standard" i still keep getting this error. or getting the "stoi() does not exist in the current scope"  error

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int test = 34;
    cout << stoi(test);
}
```

Comment: stoi doesn't take an int as argument. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol.
Either you do int test = std::stoi("34"), or you do std::cout << test;

Comment: You're looking for `std::to_string`, not for the inverse operation

Comment: @fabian or that ;) However it is not needed to output an int.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? If you want to print the value of `test`, write `cout << test;`. If you want to do something else, you need to explain what that is; `stoi` of an integer does not make sense.

Answer (score 0):

`stoi` means "String To Int". It will read an `int` from a `std::string` (or `std::wstring`). See also the [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol).

You were probably looking for the reverse `std::to_string` ([reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string)). But you don't need either, there is no need to convert to string before printing:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int test = 34;
    std::cout << test;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

stoi means string to int. So it takes a **string** as an input. 
This should work:

`string test = "34";  cout << stoi(test);`